# Need help regarding a specific type of report design by ssrs

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

i want to show one master and one detail data.

master data from sale table and detail data from phone table
there is no relation between two table only one field is common in two table that is country code.

in the first page i want to show data regarding UK like

```
UK details                it is title country wise
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Sale : 112300  Diag sale: 1300 Reman sale : 10000


Caller Name            incomming call       out going call       call transfer
----------------  ---------------------    -------------------  ----------------
keith                     5                         5                  2
john                      3                         2                  1
sam                       8                         4                  5
```

in the next page same data will come but USA data will show. so in this way country specific data will show in each page.
i am new in ssrs so i am not getting any idea how to design this report with ssrs

my store will supply data and it will take only one parameter like country code. if i pass country code like 'GB,US,DE' then my sp will return two result set first result set will fetch data from sale table for country GB,US and DE like

```
total_sale,   diag_sale, Reman_Sale, countrycode
112300         1300         10000        GB
10200          1200         4700         US
4200           1500         5600         DE
```

first result will look like above output

second result set will look like

```
callername       incommingcall    outgoingcall    calltransfer   countrycode
keith                 5                 5               5             GB
john                  3                 2               1             US
sam                   8                 4               5             DE
```

so discuss in detail how could i design this type of report with ssrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Morning,

In addition to anakulk's solution, you could display detail records using a sub report.  You would create the master report which contains the data from your sales table.  You would create another report that is based on the phone table.

On the master report, you would insert a sub report, select the report you built based on the phone table, and link it using the country code.  This way, whenever you have the UK sales information displaying, the sub report will display the details from the phone table that have UK in the country code field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about Datasets?
If yes then then in dataset query you can  join two tables to get whatever you want on report.

Now on report:-
1)You can take a tablix
2)In that tablix ,on first row you can write expression for displaying CountryName
3)on second row of tablix, you can put "Total Sale : 112300  Diag sale: 1300 Reman sale : 10000 "
4)and finally on 4th row you can put the details fields.
5)You have make a row group ,group by CountryCode.

This just a brief idea..I hope this will help you a bit to atleast start..